# Foreach / If with a CSV File

Tags: powershell, csv, if-statement, foreach

I would like to setup a script to run automatically which would read a through a CSV file and notify us if WAN1 Status is failed etc.

Please see basic script below:

"$merakicsv = Import-Csv 'C:\Python\Scripts\2020-08-11.csv'

$merakiselectedcsv = $merakicsv | select "Network", "WAN1 Status", "WAN2 Status"

Output of $merakiselectedcsv

Network                        WAN1 Status   WAN2 Status

---

NETWORK1                       Failed        Not connected

NETWORK2                       Active        Not connected

NETWORK3                       Active        Ready"

I cant quite figure out how to write the foreach to read through the CSV and I would really like some assistance / advice.

Assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Foreach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7):

```
Import-Csv 'C:\Python\Scripts\2020-08-11.csv' | Foreach-Object {
    $_ # The current row deserialized into an object with properties
    $_.Network # The current object's Network property value
}
```

Using [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7):

```
foreach ($row in (Import-Csv 'C:\Python\Scripts\2020-08-11.csv')) {
    $row # The current row deserialized into an object with properties
    $row.Network # The current object's Network property value
}
```

Using [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7) for filtering:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\Python\Scripts\2020-08-11.csv' |
    Where-Object { $_.'WAN1 Status' -eq 'Failed' } | Foreach-Object {
        $_ # Current row object that has WAN1 Status of Failed
    }
```

Using `if` statements:

```
$merakicsv = Import-Csv 'C:\Python\Scripts\2020-08-11.csv'
foreach ($row in $merakicsv) {
    if ($row.'WAN1 Status' -eq 'Active'){
        "$($row.Network) is Active!"
    } else {
        "$($row.Network) is not Active!"
    }
}
```

---

In general, I would filter a collection first before looping. This will minimize the amount of times you iterate in the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been incredibly helpful